# Incorrect camera extrinsics for simulated Gazebo cameras

Tags: ros, gazebo, rviz, gazebo-plugins

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am simulating several cameras in Gazebo using the `gazebo_ros_camera` plugin in the `gazebo_plugins` package. All of the cameras are defined in the robot's URDF and the corresponding coordinate frames are published by the `joint_state_publisher` and `robot_state_publisher` nodes.

When I view frames captured from the simulated cameras, it is clear that they are pointing in roughly the correct direction. If I view the simulated world in RViz, the visualized world renders correctly for horizontal cameras (left), but not for cameras with a non-zero pitch (right):

[image: Image from Horizontal Camera]
[image: Image from Angled Camera]

It appears that the images captured in Gazebo have approximately twice the pitch that is specified in the URDF (note how the ground plane projected by RViz is too high in the right image). Has anyone else run into a similar problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9761/incorrect-camera-extrinsics-for-simulated-gazebo-cameras/) by [mkoval](https://answers.ros.org/users/309/mkoval/) on ROS Answers with karma: 524 on 2011-04-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

For pin hole cameras that gazebo is simulating, the equation below holds,

```
focal_lengtth = image_width / (2*tan(hfov_radian / 2)
```

One way to avoid inconsistency is to NOT specify <focal_length> tag in your XML.  That way, <focal_length> is calculated using the above formula.

In addition, I'll patch gazebo_ros_camera plugin to raise an inconsistency error message when a focal_length is provided that is inconsistent with image_width and hfov.

Will that fix the problem for you?

Thanks,
John

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2011-04-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [leogeo](https://answers.ros.org/users/39061/leogeo/) on 2020-10-02**:
hi,
if i want the focal_length value in mm or pixel dimensions (pixel per mm). i have already the intrinsic parameters from calibration. ( i am using gazebo )

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the problem. In the PR2 sample code, there is a a comment above the `focal_length` element:

```
<!-- image_width / (2*tan(hfov_radian /2)) -->
<!-- 320 for wide and 772.55 for narrow stereo camera -->
<focal_length>320</focal_length>
```

I assumed that this was a PR2-specific comment and set `focal_length` to my camera's actual focal length. It turns out that *always* uses the value `image_width / (2*tan(hfov_radian / 2)`, and only uses the value of `focal_length` for publishing `camera_info`. If `focal_length` is set to a different value, the focal length used by Gazebo will not match the focal length used by RViz. Making both focal lengths match fixed the rendering differences.

---

Originally posted by [mkoval](https://answers.ros.org/users/309/mkoval/) with karma: 524 on 2011-04-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1